# Conditional Display of content on Cloudpage in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Marketing Cloud Query I am trying to display content through a cloud page with a condition. Use Case - If the subscriber is Active , Display Unsub Page Else Display Resub Page. The pages are content blocks in content builder and needs to be called in a cloudpage depending on Boolean Values of a field.

```ampscript
%%[
SET @IndividualId = AttributeValue("IndividualId")
IF Not Empty (@IndividualId) THEN
SET @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects( "Individual", "HasOptedOutSolicit", "Id", "=", @IndividualId ) 
ENDIF 

IF RowCount(@subscriberRows) > 0 THEN
SET @row = row(@subscriberRows,1) 
SET @HasOptedOutSolicit = field(@row,"HasOptedOutSolicit")
ENDIF 
]%%

%%[ IF @HasOptedOutSolicit == 'True' THEN ]%%
%%=ContentBlockbyId("XXXXX")=%%
%%[ ELSEIF @HasOptedOutSolicit == 'False' THEN ]%%
%%=ContentBlockbyId("YYYYY")=%%
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: So, what is your question? We need more explanation of what is not working as expected.

Comment: Hi Lukas, The content blocks are not getting displayed . I have tried the same script in an email message and it does render in email.

Comment: Did you check if @IndividualId is populated? You should use a combination of RedirectTo and CloudPagesUrl with parameters, to pass it to the cloudpage. Also, check how many rows are fetched by RetrieveSalesforceObjects. How do you currently link to the cloudpage from email?

Comment: Hi Lukas, Yes I am using the RedirectTo and Concating the parameters in the URL. This code does work if I am placing the html content between the IF ELSE blocks but fails with contentblockbyID to fetch from content builder.